# Field mapping with MapStruct by JsonProperty annotation

Tags: java, mapstruct

In my current project the names of the model class fields are German. The fields are all annotated with `@JsonProperty` for the English translation of the names. E.g. `@JsonProperty(value = "operation")`. Is there a way in the configuration that the mapping of the fields is done using the `JsonProperty` annotation?

Example:

```
public class Auftrag {

  @JsonProperty(value = "orderType")
  private String auftragsart;

  ...
}

public class OrderDto {
    
    private String orderType;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct uses the Java Bean convention to detect the properties. This means that it looks in the getters and setters.

Out-of-the-box you cannot use the `@JsonProperty`. However, you can create your own `AccessorNamingStrategy` that will provide the properties based on `@JsonProperty`. The `AccessorNamingStrategy` gives you access to the Abstract syntax tree, which means you can look for fields in types, check their annotations and check their values.

Keep in mind that MapStruct will only ask to get the property for a method, so you would need to get the property name, then find the field in the type, then look for the `@JsonProperty` annotation and its value.

You can read more about the `AccessorNamingStrategy` [here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy) in the documentation.