# MapStruct Field mapping between source and target using JsonProperty annotation

Tags: json, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have a requirement to map source and target object using mapstruct in a springboot project. Object has more than 700 fields and field names are completely different in both source and target object. Rather than mapping it in interface using "**@Mapping**", i would like to do it using "JsonProperty / JsonAlias" annotation. Is't possible to do it? and if yes can anyone please let me know on how to do it? any reference example.

I don't find any blogs or article with proper explanation on this.

Regards
Raj

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69013554/field-mapping-with-mapstruct-by-jsonproperty-annotation

Comment: Yes i saw that post. I was not clear on how to do it using AccessorNamingStrategy . Can anyone please share input on how to achieve this functionality using AccessorNamingStrategy.